# Google Chrome on Mac Not acting on list links

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am facing the weirdest problem with links inside a menu. Clicking on any of links doesn't do anything. I have tried giving an href for a google as well but that isn't acted upon either. As soon as I place the other divs anywhere outside they work perfectly.

**HTML:**

```
<div nom-dropdown class="nom-menu" >
   <span class="dropdown-toggle">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
   </span>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/#/">CRM</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/odp">ODP</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/olp">OLP</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/ticket">Ticket</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/" ng-click="endActiveCall()">Reset</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#/" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nom-menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
 }

.nom-menu .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
  min-width: 20px;
}

.nom-menu .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.nom-menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.nom-menu>a {
  top: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

This is most probably a mac/chrome specific issue as it seems to work fine on other browsers/linux distros.

Comment: Well your CSS syntax is WAY off to start.

Comment: I am using .styl instead of .css. Building it using gulp into a public directory. The css is served to the browser with the correct syantax.